# Malloc does not allocate suficient memory

Tags: c, malloc, clion

When running the code I check if the pointer has been allocated suficient memory or if it stays at NULL but it can be assigned the whole quantity of memory we desired. We are using C11 with Clion.

First part of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "LS_allegro.h"

#define MAX_CHAR 100

typedef struct {
    char name[MAX_CHAR];
    char escuderia[MAX_CHAR];
    int dorsal;
    int reflejos;
    int c_fisica;
    int temperamento;
    int gest_neumaticos;
}DatosPiloto;

typedef struct {
    char type[26];
    int vel;
    int acc;
    int cons;
    int fiab;
}Pieza;

typedef struct {
    char name_cat[26];
    Pieza *pieza;
    int num_piezas;
}Categorias;
```

Int main and funcion calling:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char sel[MAX_CHAR];
    int opt = 0;
    int error = 0, datosok = 0;
    // Opcion 1
    DatosPiloto datosPiloto;
    Categorias *categorias;

    if (argc == 5) {
        error = abreFichero(argv);
    }
    else {
        printf("Error. El programa tiene que recibir 4 argumentos.");
        error = 1;
    }


    if (error == 0) {
        leerArchivos(argv, &categorias);
    ...
    ...
```

argc is an integer with a value of 5 always and **argv is the pointer with the files imported in clion, where [0] is the first file and [4] is the last one.

And the function is:

```
void leerArchivos (char **argv, Categorias **categorias) {
    FILE *Piezas;
    FILE *GPs;
    FILE *Corredores;
    FILE *Base;

    int num_categorias = 0, lineas_leer = 0;
    int j = 0, i = 0, cat_count = 0;
    char basura;
    Piezas = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    GPs = fopen(argv[2], "r");
    Corredores = fopen(argv[3], "rb");
    Base = fopen(argv[4], "rb");


    fscanf(Piezas, "%d", &num_categorias);

    printf("%d\n", num_categorias);

    *categorias = (Categorias *) malloc(num_categorias * sizeof(Categorias));

    if (*categorias == NULL || sizeof(categorias) < num_categorias * sizeof(Categorias)) {
        printf("ERROR! Memory not allocated or smaller that desired.\n");
    }else {
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: `sizeof` does not tell you how mch memory has been allocated. There's no standard way to find that out. With `malloc`, you either get at least the amount of bytes you asked for or you get `NULL`. And `sizeof(categorias)` is the size of a pointer, no matter whether and how much memory is allocated to it.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` does not tell you how much memory has been allocated. There's no standard way to find that out. With `malloc()`, you either get at least the amount of bytes you asked for or you get `NULL`.  `sizeof(categorias)` is the size of a pointer, no matter whether and how much memory is allocated to it. [@M Oehm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60746274/malloc-does-not-allocate-suficient-memory#comment107477228_60746274)

The below is OK.

```
*categorias = (Categorias *) malloc(num_categorias * sizeof(Categorias));
if (*categorias == NULL) {
    printf("ERROR! Memory not allocated or smaller that desired.\n");
} else {
```

---

Cast not needed.

Allocating to the size of the referenced data is cleaner than the size of of the type.

```
*categorias = malloc(sizeof *categorias * num_categorias);
```

A value of less than  0 for `num_categorias` creates issues.  Consider an *unsigned* type.

```
// int num_categorias = 0
unsigned  num_categorias = 0
// or 
size_t num_categorias = 0
```

A value of for `num_categorias` creates issues.  Some older systems return `NULL` even when successful.

```
if (*categorias == NULL && num_categorias != 0) {
```

Comment: Ease try to repply with things about the question, we know the rest of the code and we want it that way because it needs to be like this. No unsigned, better integers, the cast in malloc... Thanks!!